# CKeditor Copy/paste image local path

Tags: javascript, web, ckeditor

When I make a copy / paste of an image in the editor "CKeditor4" the path of the image is of the type "file: //" I would like to know if it would be possible, that when I make a Copy / Paste an image, it downloads to a folder on my server and uses the server path?

I tried with all browsers Opera, Chrome, IE and Mozilla

Comment: Have you Googled `CKeditor Copy/paste image local path`? This is a very common problem and there's a ton of info on it out there.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried but the proposed solutions do not solve my problem

Comment: That could be because there's no ready-made solution yet (although this should technically be possible using the file API). Here's a statement from one of the product's creators from 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31766878/187606

Comment: Have you tried AlfonsoML's SimpleUploads? https://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/p/simpleuploads-plugin-for-ckeditor.html?m=1

Comment: I can not use the Word Paste plugin, because it puts me the message 'your browser does not allow you to paste this way. press ctrl + v to paste '

Comment: Now that would be relevant info to put into the question! Along with what browsers you're seeing that message in, etc. That would make it a more workable question for Stack Overflow; generic "how do I do X" questions aren't really on topic here, especially given that there's loads of duplicates out there.

Comment: With all the browsers precisely Opera, Chrome, Mozilla and IE

Comment: Put it in the question. Stack Overflow tries to be an archive of questions and answers valuable for future readers rather than a discussion/support forum. (The issue has been addressed though on CKEditor's Github: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/469)

Comment: And related: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/595 some users there are suggesting downgrading CKEditor

Comment: I just downgrade and actually instead of "does not allow" I have a window that opens but when I paste the image, I still have the same problem. The image does not display because it has a local path

Comment: My problem is solved I made the update 4.8 and I took the package "full" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved I made the update 4.8 and I took the package "full" and it works.